# How can set letter spacing style to jediterpane in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I added a css rule to `jeditorpane`. But only the body rule worked. The others did not.

```
Font body_font = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 8);
String bodyRule = "body { font-family: " + body_font.getFamily() + "; "
        + "font-size: " + body_font.getSize() + "pt;}";
((HTMLDocument) jEditorPane1.getDocument()).getStyleSheet().addRule(bodyRule);
String P_Rule = "P {letter-spacing:3px}";
((HTMLDocument) jEditorPane1.getDocument()).getStyleSheet().addRule(P_Rule);
String h5_Rule = "H5 {letter-spacing:3px}";
((HTMLDocument) jEditorPane1.getDocument()).getStyleSheet().addRule(h5_Rule);
MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, -0.2f);
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(set, "Courier New");
StyleConstants.setFontSize(set, 10);
set.addAttribute(TextAttribute.TRACKING, 0.5);
((HTMLDocument) jEditorPane1.getDocument()).setParagraphAttributes(0, jEditorPane1.getDocument().getLength(), set, true);
```

Comment: Where are the `P` and `H5` tags? Inside `body`? I'm not sure but did you try with smaller case `p` and `h5`?

Comment: i used p and H5 in Html Content that showed in Jediterpane..

Comment: http://java-sl.com/gp_effects.html use this to add the kerning effect